# Is it true that "if $y$ is free for $x$ in a well-formed formula $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$, then $x$ is free for $y$ in $\mathcal{B(x,y)}$?"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Two axiom schemas for first-order theories with equality are given in Mendelson's book "Introduction to Mathematical Logic (5th ed.)":

(A6) $(\forall x_1) x_1=x_1$ (reflexivity of equality)

(A7) $x=y\Rightarrow (\mathcal{B(x,x)}\Rightarrow \mathcal{B(x,y)})$ (substitutivity of equality)

where $x$ and $y$ are any variables, $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$ is a wf, and $\mathcal{B(x,y)}$ arises from $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$ by replacing some, but not necessarily all, free occurrences of $x$ by $y$,
with the proviso that $y$ is free for $x$ in $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$. Thus, $\mathcal{B(x,y)}$ may or may not
contain free occurrences of $x$.

Proposition 2.24 asserts that schema (A7) can be reduced to a few simpler cases as follows:

Proposition 2.24:
Let $K$ be a theory for which (A6) holds and (A7) holds for all atomic wfs (well-formed formulas)
$\mathcal{B(x,x)}$ in which there are no individual constants. Then $K$ is a theory with equality, that is, (A7) holds for all wfs $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$.

The proof of Proposition 2.24 is by induction on the number $n$ of connectives and quantifiers in $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$. After showing that (A7) holds for all atomic wfs $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$, the proof proceeds to the inductive step. In Case 1, i.e., $\mathcal{B(x,x)}=\neg\mathcal{C(x,x)}$, of the inductive step, it is asserted that $\vdash y=x\Rightarrow (\mathcal{C(x,y)}\Rightarrow \mathcal{C(x,x)})$ by inductive hypothesis. However, to apply the inductive hypothesis, we need "$x$ is free for $y$ in $\mathcal{C(x,y)}$" (not "$y$ is free for $x$ in $\mathcal{C(x,x)}$" that is at our disposal in this case).

So my question is: Is it true that if $y$ is free for $x$ in $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$, then $x$ is free for $y$ in $\mathcal{B(x,y)}$?" Or how to fix this proof of Proposition 2.24? Or my reasoning about the proof in Case 1 above is not correct.

Many thanks for any comments or hints.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to be fixed.

The induction step involving $\lnot$ uses the "reversed" axiom: $y = x \to (C(x,y) \to C(x,x))$ and the request is that $x$ is *free for* $y$ [see def. page 46] because we want to replace (one or more occurrences of) $y$ with $x$ into $C(x,y)$ to get $C(x,x)$.

In a nutshell, we want to avoid uncorrect substitutions like this one: $C(x,y) := Px \land \forall x (x < y)$ where the second occurrence of $x$ replacing $y$ will be "captured" by the $\forall x$ quantifier.

Having done this, the "propositional transformations" will produce: $x=y \to (\lnot C(x,x) \to \lnot C(x,y))$.

During these "transformational" steps there are no new substitutions to be performed. Thus, the proviso that $x$ must be *free for* $y$ is not used.

---

Having said that:

> Is it true that "if $y$ is free for $x$ in a well-formed formula $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$, then $x$ is free for $y$ in $\mathcal{B(x,y)}$?"

The question must be better "specified": if $\mathcal{B(x,y)}$ is obtained from $\mathcal{B(x,x)}$ **correctly** replacing one (or more) occurrences of $x$ with $y$, can we reverse the operation and replace the newly introduced $y$ with $x$ to restore the original formula?

The answer is YES, because if the operation in correctly preformed the new $y$ in $\mathcal{B(x,y)}$ is not in the scope of a $\forall y$ quantifier and thus restoring $x$ does not produce any harm.

May it happens that the "restored" $x$ will be captured by a $\forall x$ quantifier?

NO, because if so this means that the newly introduced $y$ has replaced an $x$ that was in the scope of a $\forall x$ quantifier, and this type of substitution is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments. I have come up with one example, but am not sure if it is a counterexample: If $\mathcal{B}(x,x)$ is $(\forall x)(A_1^1(x)\Rightarrow A_1^1(y))\Rightarrow (\forall z)A_1^1(x)$, then $\mathcal{B}(x,y)$ is $(\forall x)(A_1^1(x)\Rightarrow A_1^1(y))\Rightarrow (\forall z)A_1^1(y)$ and $y$ is free for $x$ in $\mathcal{B}(x,x)$, but $x$ is not free for $y$ in $\mathcal{B}(x,y)$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have corrected the formula.

Comment: Not exactly; in $(∀x)(A(x) \to A(y)) \to (∀z)A(x)$ only the last occurrence of $x$ can be used, and thus you **correctly** get:  $(∀x)(A(x) \to A(y)) \to (∀z)A(y)$. But also the "reverse" works, because the rightmost $y$ is not in the scope of a $\forall x$ quantifier and thus we can perform the subst to get  $(∀x)(A(x) \to A(y)) \to (∀z)A(x)$

Comment: Is it a good idea to revise the statement of axiom schema (A7) so that it only requires that at the places of substitutions of $x$ by $y$, $y$ won't become a bound variableafter the substitution?,

Comment: @Jason - is that not already the def of "free for"? See page 46.

Comment: Yes. I think this is where people get confused. In my example above, there are two free occurrences of $y$ in $\mathcal{B}(y,x)$ and the first free occurrence is within the scope of ($\forall x$), and hence $x$ is not free for $y$ in $\mathcal{B}(y,x)$ according to the definition on page 46. This is my understanding of the definition on page 46, but since I am a beginner there is a good chance that my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: @Jason - yes but *free for* is not *free*... It is *free* and ... The leftmost occurrence of $y$ in $B(x,x)$ is *free* but **not** *free for* $x$ (while it is free for $z$). The rightmost occurrence of $y$ in $B(x,y)$ is free and *free for* $x$ (but **not** free for $z$).

Comment: @Mauro-Yes, $y$ is free for $x$ in $\mathcal{B}(x,y)$, but what we need is $x$ is free for $y$ in $\mathcal{B}(x,y)$ (don't we?)

Comment: @Jason - sorry, I cannot understand... We have to write the formula we are working with; we need that $y$ is *free for* $x$ if we want to put $y$ in place of (free occurrences of) $x$ in it. We need $x$ *free for* $y$ if we want to put $x$ in place of $y$.

Comment: @Mauro-No problem at all. I have decided to revise the statement of axiom schema (A7) so that it only requires that the new free occurrences of $y$ arising from the substitutions of some free occurrences of $x$ by $y$ are free occurrences in $\mathcal{B}(x,y)$ (instead of the more strict condition that $y$ is free for $x$ in $\mathcal{B}(x,x)$). This modification makes it possible to apply the induction hypothesis in Case 1 of the proof of Proposition 2.34. Furthermore, In Case 3 of the proof-we need to discuss the case $z$ is $x$ or $y$ and the case $z$ is neither $x$ nor $y$ separately.